# ¿Qué función debo ocupar para evaluar el valor de una variable?

Tags: vbs

En esta macro estoy asignando un valor a la variable `warchivo`, el valor de la variable la ocupo en la primer línea de la macero, pero no funciona, ¿cuál es la función correcta?, adjunto código:

```
Sub copiarHoja_A_LibroCerrado()

warchivo = "C:\Trabajo\ejemplo.xlsm"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 
    Set libroCerrado = Workbooks.Open("warchivo")
    Sheets("Hoja 1").Copy Before:=libroCerrado.Sheets(1)
    libroCerrado.Close SaveChanges:=True
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `"warchivo"` es una cadena literal no una variable, para indicar la variable, indicala sin comillas: `Workbooks.Open(warchivo)`

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando así, tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.